# Rotate points openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I've trying to generate figures by revolution reading the profile of figure from a ply. I follow the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982253/opengl-lathe-profile-vector-faces/20005800#20005800) and other similar questioons, but my problem persist. When I try to rotate a Ply with only 2 points 36 stesps I get this if I puth the camara on the top the cilinder:

[image: cilinder ply]

My code after a revision of the method rotate is:

```
void Figura::rotateY(int ngiros){
//Variables de rotacion.
  //double alfa = 2*M_PI/ngiros;
  int long_perfil = vertices.size();

  vector<_vertex3f> new_vertices;

  cout << long_perfil << " vertices" << endl;

  _vertex3f aux1, aux2;
  for(int i=0; i < ngiros; i++){
     double alfa = (2*M_PI/ngiros)*i;
     for(int j=0;  j < long_perfil; j++){
         aux1 = vertices.at(j);
         aux1._0 = (cos(alfa) * aux1._0) + (sin(alfa) * aux1._2);
         aux1._2 = (cos(alfa) * aux1._2) - (sin(alfa) * aux1._0);

      vertices.push_back(aux1);
    }
  }

  //vertices.clear();
  //vertices = new_vertices;

  //caras
  for(int i=0; i < vertices.size(); i++){
     _vertex3i aux(i, i+1, i+long_perfil);
     _vertex3i aux2(i, i+long_perfil+1, i+1);
     caras.push_back(aux);
     caras.push_back(aux2);
     }
   }
}
```

I can't find my error. Some help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're unclear over what coordinate system your original curve is in, and how you're applying a rotation to it. With your current code, you're just rotating the points by a variable amount, but keep them all within the same plane. You can tell from just looking at the code superficially: You never set a value for the y-coordinate of any of the points, so the whole result is not a 3D shape, but entirely in the y=0 plane. As flat as a pancake...

Another thing you need to be careful about is that you don't modify values while you're still using the old value:

```
     aux1._0 = (cos(alfa) * aux1._0) + (sin(alfa) * aux1._2);
     aux1._2 = (cos(alfa) * aux1._2) - (sin(alfa) * aux1._0);
```

Here, you're modifying the value of `aux1._0` in the first statement, while the second statement should in fact still use the old value.

Let's say your original curve is in the x/y-plane, and you want to rotate around the y-axis. For this to result in a nice 3D shape, all the x-coordinates of the curve should be positive:

```
     ^ y
     |
     |--
     |  \
     |   \_
     |     |   x
--------------->
     |     |
     |    /
     |   /
     | _/
     |/
```

Picture the z-axis pointing out of the screen.

Now, to rotate this curve by a given angle *alpha* around the y-axis, we leave the y-coordinate unchanged, and rotate the point (x, 0) by *alpha* within the xz-plane to get the new values for x and z. The new coordinates (x', y', z') for input point (x, y) of the shape are then:

```
x' = x * cos(alpha)
y' = y
z' = x * sin(alpha)
```

As a modified version of your code:

```
for(int i=0; i < ngiros; i++){
    double alfa = (2*M_PI/ngiros)*i;
    for(int j=0;  j < long_perfil; j++){
        aux1 = vertices.at(j);
        aux2._0 = cos(alfa) * aux1._0;
        aux2._1 = aux1._1;
        aux2._2 = sin(alfa) * aux1._0;

        vertices.push_back(aux2);
    }
}
```